# Splitting with comma

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, split

I have meaningless numbers like 93283274658402812765.I want to do it like '9','3','2'... and plot it using matplotlib.

So far ;

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test= int(bin(93283274658402812765)[2:])
test = [str(d) for d in str(test)]
plt.axis([0, number, 0, 10])
plt.plot(test)
plt.show()
```

I get sharp transition points it should be a linear rise/fall rectangular histogram. What could be the convenient approach ?

Comment: `d` will already be of type `str`

Answer (score 2):

here, this will give you a histogram

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

test= str(93283274658402812765)
test = [int(d) for d in test]
plt.axis([0, number, 0, 10])
plt.hist(test)
plt.show()
```

You may also want to change the axis line as

```
plt.axis([min(test), max(test), 0, 10])
```

Comment: I understand but I want histogram like behavior from plt.plot().

Comment: In other words I want to convert my number to binary and have square 1,0 plot from it using plt.plot.

Comment: Do you mean in x-axis of the histogram, there should be only 0 and 1? Say if test = 37, then do you want x=0, y=0 and x=1, y=7 ?   If you want rectangles you can use plt.bar(), but then you have to calculate y values for yourself. plt.plot() plot lines only.